# Hikari. The number of ActiveConnections is increasing

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am using Hikari and connecting to Oracle.
As i understand, connections should be closed by try-block automatically. But unfortunately, after each call the ActiveConnections increases. When it reaches 100 i get exception:

> java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-2 - Connection is
> not available, request timed out after 10001ms.

[jconsole helps me to see the value of ActiveConnections][1]

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.hikari.register-mbeans = true
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name = oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=100
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
```

**Java class:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Transactional
public String getFormButtons() {
    try (
            OracleConnection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()
                                     .unwrap( OracleConnection.class );
            )
    {
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ...
    
}
```

**Key dependencies in pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>19.8.0.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Please explain me what wrong is.

**UPD.**
I have made some corrections:

1. changed
   `spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name = oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource` to
   `spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`.
2. removed artifact `@Transaction`;
3. used `HikariDataSource` instead of `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()`:

> @Autowired
> private HikariDataSource hds;

Despite this, after each call the number of ActiveConnections still increases.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution to my issue. In short, I abandoned `try-with-resource` statement and managed connection closure by myself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).